# Extract folders in gradle and create a jar

Tags: plugins, gradle

I have this structure in a zip file

```
classes
 |--com: A.class, B.class      
 |--org: C.class, D.class
 |--android: X.class
 |--stuff: Stuff.inf, info.txt
```

I want be able to extract only the folders with .class files: com, org, android. And put them on a jar.
So far I have done this:

```
task createJar {
    //unzip the file
    FileTree zip = zipTree('runtime.jar') 
    FileTree zip2 = zip.matching {
        include 'classes/**/*.class'        
    }
    zip2.each { file -> println "doing something with $file" }      

    //create the jar
    jar{        
        from zip2
        destinationDir  file('GradleTests/testResult')      
    }
}
```

But I get the jar with the classes folder on it, like: `classes/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/StringBody.class` 
And i want it like: `org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/StringBody.class`

Any idea how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think there are two main things that can get you closer to what you want:

1. Use the `zipTree` directly in the `jar` task rather than creating an intermediate zip.
2. Use `eachFile` to change the relative path of each file to strip off the first folder.

```
jar {
  from zipTree('runtime.jar') {
    include 'classes/**/*.class'
    eachFile { it.relativePath = it.relativePath.segments[1..-1] }
  }
}
```

Jar tasks have all of the [CopySpec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html#rename%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) methods, which provide the eachFile abilities.

Comment: With the current version of Gradle(1.11) this  solution won't work you will get a ClassCastException because the segments can't be casted to RelativePath. I had a similar question which has some alternative solutions. Please check out here [How to extract without first directory using Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844296/how-to-extract-without-first-directory-using-gradle?noredirect=1#comment34866075_22844296)