# How to copy files into flat directory in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to write a Gradle task to copy specific files from a deep tree into a flat folder.

#### First Try:

```
task exportProperties << {
  copy {
    from "."
    into "c:/temp/properties"
    include "**/src/main/resources/i18n/*.properties"
  }
}
```

This copies the correct files, but does not flatten the structure, so I end up with every single folder from my original project, and most of them are empty.

#### Second try, based on answers I saw [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-flatten-when-copy/5491) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091843/how-do-i-flatten-the-directory-structure-when-unzipping-with-gradle):

```
task exportProperties << {
  copy {
    from fileTree(".").files
    into "c:/temp/properties"
    include "**/src/main/resources/i18n/*.properties"
  }
}
```

This time, it is not copying anything.

#### Third Try:

```
task exportProperties << {
  copy {
    from fileTree(".").files
    into "c:/temp/properties"
    include "*.properties"
  }
}
```

Almost works, except it is copying every *.properties file when I only want the files in particular paths.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got it to work like this:

```
task exportProperties << {
  copy {
    from fileTree(".").include("**/src/main/resources/i18n/*.properties").files
    into "c:/temp/properties"
  }
}
```

Comment: I love the perlesqness of this answer

Comment: Could you help to explain a little of the grammar of this from statement? Method fileTree() retrurns a ConfigurableFileTree, and this ConfigurableFileTree has the include method which returns PatternFilterable. I could only find the getFiles() method in PatternFilterable. Where is the "files" from ? Is It due to the grammar/syntax sugar of Groovy ?

Comment: @linc01n sorry, I haven't used Gradle since a few months after I answered this question. My guess is that it is like you say, and  `myObject.xyz` is equivalent to `myObject.getXyz()`

Comment: That's exactly how it works in Groovy @Kip

Answer (score 41):

I solved the issue in a way similar to this:

```
task exportProperties << {
  copy {
    into "c:/temp/properties"
    include "**/src/main/resources/i18n/*.properties"

    // Flatten the hierarchy by setting the path
    // of all files to their respective basename
    eachFile {
      path = name
    }

    // Flattening the hierarchy leaves empty directories,
    // do not copy those
    includeEmptyDirs = false
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the only way I could get it to work when in the context of a processResources copySpec.

Answer (score 10):

You can modify a number of aspects of copied files on the fly by feeding a closure into the [Copy.eachFile](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:eachFile(groovy.lang.Closure)) method including target file path:

```
copy {
    from 'source_dir'
    into 'dest_dir'
    eachFile { details ->
        details.setRelativePath new RelativePath(true, details.name)
    }
}
```

This copies all files directly into the specified destination directory, though it also replicates the original directory structure without the files.

Comment: Use `includeEmptyDirs = false` to omit empty folders

Comment: I love this solution, because it also allows to do an arbitrary renaming based on any component of the source path. In my case, I need not just to flatten the tree, but to also rename the files based on which dir they were in. E.g. `src/en/lang.json` -> `dest/lang_en.json`. Accomplished via `eachFile { f -> f.path = new RelativePath(true, f.path.replaceFirst(/([a-z]*)\/.*/, 'lang_$1.json')) }`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in a similar way to Kip but inverted:

```
distributions {
    main {
        // other distribution configurations here...
        contents {
            into('config') {
                exclude(['server.crt', 'spotbugs-exclusion-filters.xml'])
                from fileTree('src/main/resources').files
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are no issues with empty directories when the CopySpec is configured this way.